# Zabbix trigger to compare if one item contains value from another item

Tags: triggers, zabbix, items

I have one item extracted from a JMX interrogation and I want to compare it against another one extracted from a database. These values shouldn't be equal but first one should contain/include the second - if not then I need an alert. 
Obviously I tried with `str()` function but this one doesn't accept an `{item.last}` as parameter for the `V` string:

```
{node1:ITEM1.str({node2:ITEM2.last()})}=0
```

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

That is currently not possible with the built-in functionality. While it might be possible in Zabbix 3.4, that is not fully clear yet. Please also note that only numeric values can be compared in the Zabbix trigger expressions.